# Determine the value of $a$ and $b$ such that the limit is equal to zero

Tags: calculus, limits

For what value of $a$ and $b$ is the following limit equal to zero?

$$\lim \limits_{x \to\infty}\left(\sqrt[3]{1-x^3}-ax-b\right)=0$$

Comment: Use Taylor series

Comment: @Alex ... though that would have to be around $x_0=\infty$, i.e., requires a little transformation

Comment: You're right, I didn't look at the limit.

Answer (score 5):

You want $\sqrt[3]{1-x^3}\approx ax+b$, i.e., 
$$1-x^3\approx b^3+3ab^2x+ 3a^2bx^2+a^3x^3$$
for large $x$. So we sould have $a^3=-1$ (i.e., $a=-1$) and $b=0$. Verify that this works.

Comment: Typo in $3a^2bx^2$

Comment: @Hagen von Eitzen in your solution i think $b=1$ and not equal to zero

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Write it as $$\lim_{y\to 0} \left(\sqrt[3]{1-\frac1{y^3}}-\frac ay-b\right)=0$$

I.e. $$\lim_{y\to 0}\frac{-\sqrt[3]{1-y^3}-a-by}{y}=0$$

is it familiar?

Answer (score 1):

Proceed methodically :

- first find $a$ : divide the expression by x, you want $\lim_\infty (\sqrt[3]{\frac 1 {x^3}-1}-a-\frac b x) = -1-a=0$, hence $a=-1$
- Next is $b$. Simply calculate the limit of $\sqrt[3]{1-x^3}+x$ and set $b$ equal to the opposite.

This is a standard procedure when you want to approximate asymptotically a function by an affine function : first divide by x and find the limit to find $a$, then substract $ax$ and find $b$

Comment: Ummm... and when you "divide by $x$", where does that $x$ disappear? It should be there, between the $\lim$ and the left bracket.

Comment: No, in the first step you actually calculate the limit of $\frac {f(x)} x$ to find $a$, you don't simply factor by $x$

Comment: That's fine, but then you should modify the wording *"divide the expression by $x$"*.

Answer (score 1):

$$\lim \limits_{x \to\infty}\left(\sqrt[3]{1-x^3}-ax-b\right)=0$$

You can solve this by finding the oblique asymptote to $y = \sqrt[3]{1-x^3}$.

$$y=\sqrt[3]{1-x^3}$$

$$y^3=1-x^3$$

$$x^3 + y^3 = 1$$

As $x$ gets positive and large, $y \approx -x$. So the oblique asymptote is $y=-x$.

By subtracting the oblique asymptote from $\sqrt[3]{1-x^3}$, you will ensure that the new function will tend to 0 as $x$ tends to infinity.

Therefore, $a = -1$ and $b = 0$.

Answer (score 1):

$\lim \limits_{x \to\infty}\left(\sqrt[3]{1-x^3}\right) \to -x$

Thus the equation simplfies to:

> $ \lim \limits_{x \to \infty}\left(-x - ax - b \right) = 0$
>
> $ \lim \limits_{x \to \infty}\left((1 + a)(-x) - b \right) = 0$

so a must be -1, and b must be 0.

Comment: What do you mean by $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}\sqrt[3]{1-x^3}\to -x$, precisely? $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty} f(x)$ is defined to be a real number, not a function. Also, what your expression might stand for looks a lot like what you should be proving.

Comment: $\lim \limits_{x \to\infty}\left(\sqrt[3]{1-x^3}\right) = \lim \limits_{x \to\infty}\left(\sqrt[3]{-x^3 (1- \dfrac{1}{x^3}})\right)$ so the value approaches $-x$

Comment: I still do not see a proper definition, and my suspects of an abuse of notation are intensifying.